# How to map my model data (list) with another viewmodel data (list) MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, database, viewmodel

How to map my model data (list) with another viewmodel data (list) in this case?

Here is what i have:

My json viewmodel

```
public class JsonViewModel
{
    public List<JsonItem> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class JsonItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemStock { get; set; } 
}
```

---

My main Model

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int QuantityInPack { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
}
```

which should be mapped in this way:

- `Item.QuantityInPack = JsonItem.Unit`
- `Item.Price = JsonItem.Price`

where `Item.Name = JsonItem.Name`

---

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // 1. Perform HTTP request to retrieve the JSON.
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    string rawJson = webClient.DownloadString("http://my_json_data");

    // 2. Parse the JSON.
    var jsonRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonViewModel>(rawJson);

    // 3. Map to viewmodel
    var viewModel = new JsonViewModel
    {
        Items = jsonRootObject.Items.Select(i => new JsonItem
        {
            Name = i.Name,
                    Unit = i.Unit,
                    Price = i.Price
        }).ToList()
    };



    /// var TestItem = db.Items.ToList();
    /// TestItem.QuantityInPack = JsonItem.Unit
    /// TestItem.Price = JsonItem.Price
    ///     where Item.Name = JsonItem.Name
    ///
    /// (I know it's a bad, but I wanted to explain what I mean)
    /// Here i should map data in some way
    /// 
    ///

    // 4. Return mapped model to view
    return View( TestItem??? );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to look for something similar like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) which could map you these fields using [conventions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conventions). If that's not enough you could supply it your own custom [resolvers](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers).

Comment: Also I don't want to get you off the rails, but I would like to suggest that you move out the viewmodel building logic into it's on [abstraction](http://benfoster.io/blog/using-the-view-factory-pattern-in-aspnet-mvc), which could help you keep your controller lightweight and you would only need to test your viewmodel builder for correct [behaviour](http://googletesting.blogspot.hu/2013/08/testing-on-toilet-test-behavior-not.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood right, you want to synchronize `JsonViewModel` with main model and return synchronized main model to view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
    var itemList = db.Items.ToList();
    if (jsonRootObject.Items != null)
    {
        jsonRootObject.Items.ForEach(i =>
        {
            var item = itemList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name = i.Name);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.QuantityInPack = i.Unit;
                item.Price = i.Price;
            }
        });
    }
    return View(itemList);
}
```

Comment: This is it! Tell me please, if i want to do something with this mapped record i need to update this by **db.SaveChanges();** (before return View(itemList);). 

However i guess it's really bad practice (because this method method is invoked every few seconds by AJAX) - so when should i update this record to database?

Comment: @Piter you can track changes. if some jsonModel property != mainModel property then save to db

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand what you want and db means dbContext, try this:

```
var names = viewModel.Items.Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); 
var TestItems = db.Items.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

var result = (from item in TestItems 
             join json in viewModel.Items on item.Name equals json.Name
             into subJsons from subJson in subJsons.DefaultIfEmpty() 
             select new { item, subJson }).ToList().
             Select(x => {
                  var newItem = x.item;
                  if(subJson != null)
                  {
                       newItem.QuantityInPack = x.subJson.Unit; 
                       newItem.Price = x.subJson.Price;
                  }
                  return newItem;
             }).ToList();

 return View(result);
```

Comment: This query is an implementation of left join, i.e. if one of items at Test Items will not have pair from viewModel.Items it still remains in result. Without that some items may be excluded from result: `if(subJson != null)` is checking of pair existing.